# Non Clustered Index is not visible in Execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have implemented **SQL Server's Change Data Capture** feature in my database. When you enable CDC in your database , sql server will create  some system tables for you like : **cdc.dbo_Person_CT** for tracking the changes you have in main **Person** table . I am using **cdc.dbo_Person_CT** table  and i have applied **Non-Clustered index** on a column and i am using that column in select statement.

But when i see execution plan for my table ,it doesn't show Non-Clustered index ?? why

Comment: Because the optimizer doesn't think the non-clustered index is necessary for optimal performance for the query.

Comment: Yes you are right.May be because that column is Primary key in Main (Person) table .   But i want to apply Non-clustered index for better search result in select query. Any ways  to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

We would have to see the query and the index details but I would guess that the query is returning so many rows or that the index is not exclusive enough so the query analyzer decided to use a scan instead.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than an answer.

Comment: User 2750xxx asked why and I explained why.